# Virtual Disk Manager: The service cannot be started

Tags: partitioning, ssd

I installed a SSD disk in my computer and installed Windows 7 in it. I disabled defragmentation on the disk. Now when I try to partition my other disk I'm getting an error

> Virtual Disk Manager
>
> The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.

Well, I'm not willing to enable defragmentation because it makes the lifespan of the SSD shorter.

Solutions?

Thanks

Comment: How did you 'disable' disk defrag?

Comment: Well I think I managed to enable defragmentation on other disks. I ran defrag and set it to defrag only E and F, not C which is the SSD.

Comment: There is no need to disable defragmentation on Windows 7. Windows 7 is smart enough to recognize an SSD and knows not to defragment it.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but I found myself in the same situation, and this question is near the top of Google results. So here goes:

As explained in [this forum post](http://www.sevenforums.com/performance-maintenance/79241-virtual-disk-manager.html), the virtual disk manager is tied to the defrag service. My Windows 7 machine disabled the defragmentation service right after it detected it runs on an SSD following a migration.

To enable:

1. type <kbd>Start</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and run `services.msc` from the popup window
2. Scroll down until you find the `Disk Defragmenter` service in the list. Its startup type should be `Disabled`.
3. Right click on it and select `Properties`. From there, setting the startup type to `Manual` worked for me: The service doesn't if not needed, and it doesn't appear to run at all after I fixed my partitions.

---

To address another point in your question:

> I'm not willing to enable defragmentation because it makes the lifespan of the SSD shorter

Windows (starting I think with Vista) is smart enough to know not to defrag SSD drives. Well, it doesn't skip defragmentation completely, but it adjusts it to the SSD's needs. According to [this blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheRealAndCompleteStoryDoesWindowsDefragmentYourSSD.aspx)

> Storage Optimizer will defrag an SSD once a month if volume snapshots are enabled. This is necessary due to slow volsnap copy on write performance on fragmented SSD volumes. [...] If an SSD gets too fragmented you can hit maximum file fragmentation (when the metadata can’t represent any more file fragments) which will result in errors when you try to write/extend a file. Furthermore, more file fragments means more metadata to process while reading/writing a file, which can lead to slower performance.

I should point out that maximum file fragmentation is hard to reach for a home user, but in any case there shouldn't be a problem letting Windows do its thing. It probably knows best.

Also seeing that my answer is 3 years late, I'm happy to report that (according to popular wisdom) SSD lifespan is not as bad as it once were.